# Using QT .qrc File with Visual Studio Proj...?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I have a Visual Studio 2017 project that is built with QT and VTK using CMake. I need to use image resources, and wish to use QT's .qrc resource system.

Information on this seems rare and complex when not using a QT project file. I have found this:

> 1. Create a .qrc file that contains a list of the resources you would like to include
> 2. Create a custom build step that invokes rcc on that file (documentation)
> 3. Compile and link the resulting cpp source file into your program.
>
> [How to use Qt resource files in Visual Studio without a Qt project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56035630/how-to-use-qt-resource-files-in-visual-studio-without-a-qt-project)

I am just completely confused right now on what the proper way to go about this is, and this is not enough information.

Comment: All three points you mentioned are correct. Which one you failed to perform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your CMake:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
```

This will run moc and rcc compiler automatically.

Then use the following to add the resources and link them

```
# Compiles binary resources into source code and puts the names into RESOURCES variable
qt5_add_resources(RESOURCES example.qrc)

# Adds the RESOURCES source code to your application so it will be linked
# and part of your executable
add_executable(exampleApplication main.cpp ${RESOURCES})
```

---

Further reading:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-command-reference.html
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-cmake-qt5-add-resources.html
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-cmake-qt5-add-binary-resources.html
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-cmake-qt5-add-big-resources.html

Comment: thank you so much, I just don't understand the second block... specifically the add executable, I already have something like that in my CMake file.

Comment: @AlexanderAlexander I have added some more explanation. I hope that makes it clearer. Otherwise you will have to explain what you don't understand specifically.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments I am just confused where to place the second block. Can I just put it at end of CMake file, after the autoMOC and RCC?

Comment: I also already call add_executable in my file so adding this one causes an error when building

Comment: You put `qt5_add_resources` before your `add_executable` call and add `${RESOURCES}` to your already existing `add_executable` just like you would any additional file.