# QT Framewrok and Visual Studio - icon conflict

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, icons

**Introduction**

I need to set a icon, both for .exe file, in top-left corner of my app window, and on the task bar (Windows 10). However it works only partially - I'm able to set .exe icon, but that's it. In the other two places I have default icon. I'm working with QT 5.9.7 inside Visual Studio 2017.

**What I tested so far**

I have following line in my `.rc` file:

```
IDI_ICON1               ICON                    "favicon.ico"
```

Which lets me to have .exe icon. But it seems to not affect the rest of framework. I was trying to set in-app icon this way (`main.cpp`):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/favicon.ico"));
    // a.setWindowIcon also doesn't work.
    return a.exec();
}
```

or even inside `mainwindow.cpp`

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/favicon.ico"));
}
```

However it seems to be ignored - it has no effect, also it doesn't give me any error. I also tried to include `imageformats/qico.dll` folllowing [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891591/ico-icons-not-showing-up-on-windows) instruction - still no luck.

**The Question**

So - how to set this two other icons correctly - on Windows task bar, and in the corner of my application window?

**EDIT:**
Adding `qrc` file also doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: a quick google turned up https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/appicon.html

Comment: Hi @AlanBirtles, look again on my question. I already did it, and it only set the icon for .exe file. So not a solution.

Comment: Your icon needs to be in a `qrc` file to be loadable using the `:/favicon.ico` filename:https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html

Comment: Once again - I don't use QT Creator, I Use Visual Studio. I tried for test adding it to ```qrc``` and nothing changed. I think Visuals Studio doesn't use ```qrc``` files at all.

Comment: I don't think using visual studio is relevant, QT still only loads resources from its own resource system not from the windows executable resources

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212391/microsoft-visual-studio-loading-resources-in-qt-application-without-plug-in.

Comment: Maybe you are right but adding it to ```qrc``` file didn't work anyway. Maybe some extra steps are required? Anyway - other graphic I load from file, not from resource, so why in this case should I do other way? ```:/favicon.ico``` in this case is a path, and I have ```ico``` in the app directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution, so I will post it here, in the case someone else will encounter the same problem:

First of all - the thing has nothing to do with `.rc` or `.qrc` file, the icon can be even loaded directly from app directory. The problem is in the supported formats - for some reason, under Windows 10 there is an issue with `.ico` format in QT framework. Theoretically addition of `imageformats/qico.dll` should fix the issue, but it doesn't. The solution is to use other format (in my case `.png`), and place it directly where the `.exe` file is, not in any subdirectory. Then you can call it like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    a.setWindowIcon(QIcon("favicon.png"));
    return a.exec();
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to have icon compiled in binary form, you can try to add it to resources, however the format still mustn't be `.ico` to make it works, as this is the origin of the issue. The size of the icon is adjusted correctly, so it look good both in the corner of app window, and on the task bar - therefore `.png` is fairly enough in this case.

Comment: This is correct, however for me under WIN 10 and QT 5.15.2 using .ico works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are not using Creator / qmake, you need to follow the steps from the Qt Documentation:

> If you do not use qmake, the necessary steps are: first, create an .rc
>   file and run the rc or windres program on the .rc file, then link your
>   application with the resulting .res file.

That will create the icon for the Windows Explorer / Taskbar.

The top left icon is created by adding it to the qrc file and compiling it with the resource compiler. This icon needs to be set by calling `app.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/favicon.ico"));` where app is your QApplication-instance.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however the solution is a bit different. For more details look my "self-answer".